# Intercepting all REST and SOAP request and response made from local web application

Tags: python, wireshark, packet-sniffers, sniffing

So idea is similar to wireshark . I have my application codebase (Java) which makes large number of REST and SOAP calls . Each REST and SOAP call is associated with a module . For example :

```
Class ListingModule { 
   // Makes  REST call to get Listing Details 
}

Class ProductDetailsModule { 
     //Makes REST call to get Product Details 
}

Class LocationModule { 
       //Makes SOAP call to get location details 
}
```

Similarly there are large number of modules , and many of  this calls are made in parallel . And many times the REST or SOAP calls are made from .class files (ie:Internal Libraries ) . So during debugging it becomes a great problem to know response from many modules .

I want to create a wireshark like tool in **Python** ,which would trace all the REST and SOAP request made from my local application (The local application will be running on `localhost:8080` .

So overall .

1. Create a python app that would run continuously and intercept all REST and SOAP calls made by my application .
2. I know ***Wireshark*** does the same ,but I want to create my own python app which I can enhance further to add my own specific modules like analysis ,db calls trace( but that's out of context for now ) . ***So using ready made wireshark tool is out of question*** .
3. I did my some homework , and find libraries like libcap,scapy etc. But not sure would they do the work ? I would love to have suggestion and advice .

Any advice or lead on it would be appreciated . I would definitely update my question incase if anything is not clear .

Comment: It depends what you mean by "intercept". Wireshark doesn't "intercept" packets, it sniffs them. It's very different: packets still go through, you're just logging them.

Comment: Intercept Means ,I want to know the HTTP REST  request and the response made from my application .

Comment: So you mean sniff. Yeah you can use scapy or libpcap. (does that answer your question?!) Watch out this question falls in the "asking for tools" category which usually get closed.

Comment: @Cukic0d I think , let me confirm with you . Let's say my Local Java application (Running on eclipse tomcat ) is making 100 REST and SOAP calls (Lets say endpoint for those res/soap is https://qa.xyz.com/v1/)   . And if I run my python script (written using scapy or libcap) ,will it be able to show/print the request , response of all the HTTP rest calls made from my java application ? if I am able to trace/intercept/sniff and get the HTTP REST/SOAP request and response made by my java application then I think that would help . ?

Comment: Assuming the data isn't encrypted (if you're using https you'll have to use mitmproxy), yeah sure. In scapy for instance, have a look at the `sniff()` command

Comment: Yes its https . Thank you so much Cukic0d. I'll check once and then mark this question as answered and close it . Thank you so much .

Comment: @Cukic0d Can you please post your comment as answer , your suggestion to use scapy with sniff ()  helped me and would like to marks it as  answer .